# CustomView inherited from LinearLayout but i don't know what the context is

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-context

I'm making Indicator dot with ViewPager
and this is CircleIndicator Class inherited from LinearLayout

```
class CircleIndicator: LinearLayout {

  private var mContext: Context? = null 

  constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {

      mContext = context
  }

  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {

      mContext = context
  }
```

and it's my MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewPagerContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.example.android_kotlin_viewpager_indicator.util.CircleIndicator
      android:id="@+id/indicator"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPagerContainer"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

so in this code and in the CircleIndicator Class
what is the context in the parameter of the constructor of CircleIndicator class? Does it might be a ConstraintLayout because the XML tag which is the CircleIndicator I made is the child view of the ConstraintLayout??
please help me!!

Comment: I think the context is gonna be the activity context with which you inflate the layout. Views have access to the context where they are inflated.

Comment: @Goodie123 you're right, i found out the context is the MainActivity. thank you!